# Can bootstrap modal can be blocked?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popup, modal-dialog, block, bootstrap-modal

Can bootstrap modal dialog can be blocked by any pop-up blockers like integrated blocker in Chrome. Or different ad-blocks popup blockers? 
If you don`t understand what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes and no.

Native blockers definitely don't do it, they work only with the pop-ups that open in new windows/tabs.

Adblockers can be configured to block them by classname or id or some other way to identify them, but they definitely don't block bootstrap modals out of the box.

So if the question is "Can it be that the bootstrap modal on my site is blocked by some adblocker by default?" The answer is no.

On the other hand if the question is "Can I somehow block the bootstrap modal dialog with a help of popup-/ad-blocker?". The answer is yes, by using the one that allows to block elements on the page by classname, id or other attributes.